# Parsing an internet address string into usable parts

Tags: vb.net, string, parsing, networking

Is there a library that parses an ftp string into parts for vb.net?

I need to parse this string into
"ftps://192.168.1.50/testdir/data_base"

protocol= "ftps://"

hostname: "192.168.1.50"

datadirectory: "/testdir/data_base"

Any good ideas are appreciatted.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the System.Uri class.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim uri As New Uri("ftps://192.168.1.50/testdir/data_base")
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri)
Console.WriteLine(uri.PathAndQuery)
```

returns

- "ftps://192.168.1.50/testdir/data_base"
- /testdir/data_base
- "ftps:"